# Swift instagram clone : loading followed user post

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I' m trying to make an instagram clone with swift, based on the Ribbit tuto. People can share photos and follow other users etc etc. I made a `PFRelation` between users using Parse. What i would like to do now, is to show in my `WalltableViewController`, only the followed users post.

I made a function to load all the post in a `NSMutable` array called `timeLineData`.

I ve even made a function to get the followed users ina `NSMutableArray` called `followedFriends`..

But i don't succeed in filtering the loading post function with `followedFriends`. I have this error : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'`, reason: `'Cannot do a comparison query for type: __NSArrayM'`

Here is my code :

```
 import UIKit
 import QuartzCore

class WallTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var posterAvatar: UIImageView!

   override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }


     var timeLineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray ()
    var followedFriends:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray ()

     func loadUser () {

    followedFriends.removeAllObjects()
    var friendsRelation: AnyObject! = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("KfriendsRelation")


var findUser : PFQuery = friendsRelation.query()


findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil) {
        // The find succeeded.
        println("succesfull load Users")
        // Do something with the found objects
        for object  in objects  {
            self.followedFriends.addObject(object)
            println("users added to userlist")

            for item in self.followedFriends {
                println(item)                    }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("error loadind user ")

    }

   }
  }


   func loadPost () {

  timeLineData.removeAllObjects()

   let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    var findPost:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPost")


   findPost.whereKey("from", equalTo: followedFriends )


    findPost.orderByDescending("createdAt")


    findPost.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("current user post finded")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object  in objects  {
                self.timeLineData.addObject(object)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("error loadind user post")
        }


    }

}


 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return timeLineData.count
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:WallTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WallTableViewCell

   let userPost:PFObject = self.timeLineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

//define the username

var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userPost.objectForKey("from").objectId)

findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    if !(error != nil) {
        if let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser {
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            // define avatar poster

               if let avatarImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as? PFFile {
                avatarImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)->    Void in

                    if !(error != nil) {

                        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)


                        cell.posterAvatar.image = image as UIImage
                        cell.posterAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 24
                        cell.posterAvatar.clipsToBounds = true

                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                cell.posterAvatar.image = UIImage(named: "Avatar-1")
                cell.posterAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 24
                cell.posterAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }

    }

}

//define the imagepost

let imagesPost:PFFile = userPost["imageFile"] as PFFile


imagesPost.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)-> Void in

    if !(error != nil) {

        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

        cell.imagePosted.image = image as UIImage


    }
    else {
        println("error")
    }
  }


      return cell
     }


  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
       if (currentUser != nil) {
     println("User allready logued")
      }

    else {
    // Show the signup or login screen

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToLogIn", sender: self)
    }

    }


  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

   tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   self.loadUser()
  self.loadPost()
   self.tableView.reloadData()

  }
  }
```

Comment: Is the error on this line: findPost.whereKey("from", equalTo: followedFriends ) ? because it looks like you're trying to compare the value of a single field to an entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also founded this solution :

```
   //query for the friends of the user
var friendsRelation: AnyObject! = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("KfriendsRelation")
var findFriends : PFQuery = friendsRelation.query()

 //using the friends from the query above, we find all the posts of the friends of the current    user
var findPosts:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPost")
findPosts.whereKey("from", matchesQuery:findFriends)
findPost.orderByDescending("createdAt")

 //run the query
 findPosts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil) {
        //found posts

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("error loadind posts ")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

FollowedFriends is an array, so you need to use `containedIn`. You use `equalTo` if you're comparing to one individual object. Change it to this.

```
findPost.whereKey("from", containedIn:followedFriends)
```